# What is the point of the return in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, return

I've recently been learning javascript and  came across the return statement or whatever it is. I've watched tutorials on it and I still don't get the point of it. Do I ever need it for anything and can someone please explain in detail what it does? Thanks

Comment: Just follow a good tutorial like http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript and you won't have questions like this.

Comment: The return statement exists in pretty much all languages. It is used to... ahm... return a result from a function. In JS `return;` is the same as `return undefined;`, which means "exit the function and return undefined to the caller"

Answer (score 1):

The return statement has multiple uses:

1)  Return early from your function before the end of the function body.  This is often within a branch of the code as in:

```
function whatever()
    // do some things
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
    // other code here that will not execute if there was an err
}
```

2)  Return a specific value back to the caller as in:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var sum = add(3,4);
console.log(sum);     // will show 7
```

The `return` statement in javascript can be used by itself to just exit the current function call and not return a specific value or it can be used to return a specific value.

If no return statement is present in a function, then the function will execute to the end of the function body and will return automatically at the end of the function body.

Answer (score 0):

The only point of it is to send a value (string, number, or other values) from your function so that is can be used outside the function. *Instead you can use global variables but that takes up more code, so it's a shortcut instead.*

**jfreind00** above said that you can use it to branch off early but that's what **break**. Here is the syntax:

`function HiThere(something) {
    if (something === true) {
        break;
    }
        alert("Hi");
}`

In this case, if something is true, then exit the function, if not then say hi.
Return would be like this:

`function HiThere(something) {
    if (something === true) {
        return "Value to return: " + something;
    }
        alert("Hi");
}`

In this case, if something is true, then exit the function **and** return Value to return: true, if not then say hi but don't return anything back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most common use of the `return` statement:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(5,3); // Call a function
// to set the "demo" element to the value of: 5 * 3

function myFunction(a,b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Use it to return a value.  Your value could be "Yes", "false", "hello world" or "eat dirt."  You can then run certain code based on the returned value.

Hope this helps!